Checking a candidate majority element: Does my simplification work with all cases?
Here are the details of the problem:

Given a sorted array arr of N elements.
A majority element in an array of size N is an element that appears more than N/2 times.
The task is to write a function say isMajority() that takes an array (arr[]), array’s size (n) and a number to be searched (x) as parameters and returns true if x is a majority element (present more than n/2 times).

The solution states that the lastIndex in the loop should be conditioned.

static boolean isMajority(int arr[], int n, int x)
    {
        int i, last_index = 0;

        /* get last index according to n (even or odd) */
        last_index = (n%2==0)? n/2: n/2+1;

        /* search for first occurrence of x in arr[]*/
        for (i = 0; i < last_index; i++)
        {
            /* check if x is present and is present more
               than n/2 times */
            if (arr[i] == x && arr[i+n/2] == x)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


I tried something else and it worked for some examples I have tried. But I am not sure whether it should really work with all cases or not.
public static boolean isMajority(int[]array,int x){
        int lastIndex=array.length-(array.length/2+1);
        for(int i=0;i<=lastIndex;i++){
            if(array[i]==x && array[i]==array[i+array.length/2]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


I don't think any human could have written this code thinking that it solves the stated problem.

@MattTimmermans you mean my code?

Your code assumes that array is sorted, but statement does not claim this

@MBo yeah sorry I edited the problem ,ow. It is stated that it is sorted already

Try extreme cases: n zeroes followed by n ones, by n+-1 ones.

(I think the solution weird: it does not check arr[last_index] == x upfront and uses linear search for the first x instead of binary. Your modification uses a different value where (n+1)/2 was simple enough and identical.)

You can try this below code, it will pass all the test cases:
class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int count = 1;
        int candidate = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == candidate) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    candidate = arr[i];
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return candidate;
    }
}


This does not answer Does the modified isMajority() work with all cases? The code presented looks the standard solution to "the majority element problem"; the precondition that input is ordered was made explicit after this was posted as an answer.
